# How do I get the wxpython combo box selection and change value?

Tags: python, wxpython

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx


class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(430,550))
        self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(0,500))

        self.data1 = [1,2,3]
        self.data2 = ['google','amazon']

        self.listCtrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.mainPanel, size=(0,0), style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, 'ONE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, 'TWO', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(2, 'THREE', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE, width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)

        self.ComboBoxs = wx.ComboBox(self.mainPanel, choices=self.data2, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.ComboBoxs.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.ComboSelect, self.ComboBoxs)

        self.textLabel = wx.StaticText(self.mainPanel)
        self.autoRefreshCount = 0

        self.BoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.BoxSizer.Add(self.ComboBoxs, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.BoxSizer.Add(self.listCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.BoxSizer.Add(self.textLabel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainPanel.SetSizer(self.BoxSizer)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.autoRefresh, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(5000)

        self.ComboSelect(self)

    def ComboSelect(self, event):
        self.listCtrl.Append(self.data1)

    def autoRefresh(self, evnet):
        if self.ComboBoxs.GetStringSelection() in self.data2:
            self.ComboSelect(self)
            self.textLabel.SetLabel('count : ' + str(self.autoRefreshCount))
            self.autoRefreshCount += 1
        else:
            self.textLabel.SetLabel('count : ' + str(0))
            self.autoRefreshCount = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have created an automatic import after the combo box selection value.

If the problem changes the combo box selection, the changed value `self.textLabel.SetLabel ('count:' + str (self.autoRefreshCount))` must be initialized.

I've tried a lot but I do not know how to do it.

`if self.ComboBoxs.GetStringSelection () in self.data2:` There seems to be a problem in the conditional expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve in this code.
Your test `if self.ComboBoxs.GetStringSelection() in self.data2:` is always going to be `True` because `self.ComboBoxs` is read only and therefore cannot change, so whatever the selection is, it will always be in `self.data2`.
Try the following replacement and see if it gets you closer to what you want.

```
    def ComboSelect(self, event):
#        self.listCtrl.Append(self.data1)
        self.autoRefreshCount = 0

    def autoRefresh(self, evnet):
#        if self.ComboBoxs.GetStringSelection() in self.data2:
#            self.ComboSelect(self)
        self.listCtrl.Append(self.data1)
        self.textLabel.SetLabel('count : ' + str(self.autoRefreshCount))
        self.autoRefreshCount += 1
#        else:
#            self.textLabel.SetLabel('count : ' + str(0))
#            self.autoRefreshCount = 0
```

Edit:
based on your comment, I suspect that you want is `EVT_TEXT` this event fires when the text in the combobox changes.
Bind it like this and see if this was what you were looking for.

```
self.ComboBoxs.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.ComboChange, self.ComboBoxs)
```

Comment: Thank you again. I learned a lot from you once again. I thought there was a median value that changed when the combo box changed, but it was not. Have a nice day :)